# Three table link together using foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

1. order_table

   - id
   - user_name
   - foodid
   - drinkid
2. food

   - foodid
   - name
3. drink

   - drinkid
   - name

command as follow
Create order_table table-------------------------------------------------

```
create table order_table(
id int not null auto_increment, 
user_name varchar(26) not null, 
foodid int(11) not null, 
drinkid int(11) not null, 
primary key(id), 
FOREIGN KEY (foodid) REFERENCES food(foodid),
FOREIGN KEY (drinkid) REFERENCES food(drinkid)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

Create food table -------------------------------------------------------

```
create table food (
foodid int(11) not null auto_increment, 
name varchar(26) not null, 
primary key(foodid)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

Create drink table ------------------------------------------------------

```
create table drink (
drinkid int(11) not null auto_increment, 
name varchar(26) not null, 
primary key(drinkid)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

Now i meet problem is

```
ERROR 1005 : Can't create table 't.order_table' (errno: 150)
```

which t is my database name
so what can i do for this code, thanks every body.

Comment: The `FOREIGN KEY` definition should have `()` around the column name:  `FOREIGN KEY (foodid) REFERENCES food (foodid)`

Comment: thank to  Michael Berkowski, now i add () this sign in code and execute it, show error as follow----ERROR 1005 : Can't create table 't.order_table' (errno: 150)---

Comment: There are a couple of problems in addition to the one I mentioned above. I detailed them below.

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues to correct. First, the `FOREIGN KEY` definition needs `()` surrounding the column name as in:

```
FOREIGN KEY (foodid) REFERENCES food (foodid),
/*---------^^^^^^^^^^----------------^^^^^^^^*/
```

Second, your `drinkid` foreign key definition is referencing the wrong table, `food`, instead of `drink`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (drinkid) REFERENCES drink(drinkid)
```

Finally, you must rearrange the table order so that `order_table` is created *after* the two tables it references. Put it all together.  It will then execute correctly, as in this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3aee

```
create table food (
  foodid int(11) not null auto_increment, 
  name varchar(26) not null, 
  primary key(foodid)
)ENGINE=innodb;

create table drink (
  drinkid int(11) not null auto_increment, 
  name varchar(26) not null, 
  primary key(drinkid)
)ENGINE=innodb;

create table order_table(
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  user_name varchar(26) not null, 
  foodid int(11) not null, 
  drinkid int(11) not null, 
  primary key(id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (foodid) REFERENCES food(foodid),
  FOREIGN KEY (drinkid) REFERENCES drink(drinkid)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for you, i recreate database then reexcute your code, i solve it.

Comment: Other question, What method to check the foreign key which field be comment...thx

Comment: @user1753112 I don't understand what you mean